# np where : can't compare datetime.date to unicode

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to do a `np.where` in a dataframe and separate the date that are from 2017 or more and below 2017.
I need to compare a column "Creation_Date" (date format "%d/%m/%Y") with the value '01/01/2017'.
I keep getting the same error which is : `can't compare datetime.date to unicode`

I have converted a "Creation_Date" column to a date format using the function `strftime`. Then I have converted the value '01/01/2017' to date format to compare it with the values in the "Creation_Date" column.

Here is the actual code :

```
my_df['temp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Creation_Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

t1 = my_df['temp_date'] >= dt.date(2017, 1, 1)

my_df['Final_Date'] = np.where(t1,'2017 or more','Below 2017')
```

Also tried :

```
my_df['temp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Creation_Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

t1 = my_df['temp_date'] >= dt.datetime.strptime('01/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y')

my_df['Final_Date'] = np.where(t1,'2017 or more','Below 2017')
```

I still can't manage to get the right format between these comparison : can't compare datetime.date to unicode.
I need to get a Final_Date column that distinguish the Creation_Date from 2017 or more and below 2017.

Can you help me, please ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code,

```
my_df['temp_date'] = pd.to_datetime(my_df['Creation_Date'], dayfirst=True).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

then `my_df['temp_date']` are strings, so you can't really compare them to `dt.date(2017, 1, 1)` or `dt.datetime.strptime('01/01/2017','%d/%m/%Y')` which are both `datetime` type.

On the other hand, `pandas` allows comparison between `pandas.Datetime` type and date string. So you can get rid of `dt.strftime` and you can compare:

```
my_df['temp_date']=pd.to_datetime(my_df['Creation_Date'], dayfirst=True)
my_df['temp_date'] >= '2017-01-01'
```